# Speed of sound and diffusion in relativistic hydrodynamics

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, dispersion

In the following the second part of the question [Relativistic hydrodynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/591931/relativistic-hydrodynamics) is presented:

Consider the hydrodynamic energy-momentum tensor in 3 + 1 dimensions in
at space with
the Minkowski metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$. The coordinates are chosen as $u^\mu = (t; x; y; z)$. To first order in
derivatives, the energy-momentum tensor can be written as
$T^{\mu\nu}=(\epsilon+P)u^\mu u^\nu+P\eta^{\mu\nu}-\eta\Delta^{\mu\alpha} \Delta^{\nu\beta}(\partial_\alpha u_\beta + \partial_\beta u_\alpha -\frac{2}{3}\eta_{\alpha\beta}\partial_\lambda u^\lambda)$

The
velocity vector field $u^\mu$ is normalised to $u^\mu u_\mu=-1$ and pressure is a function of energy
density, $P(\epsilon)$ (this function is the equation of state). The coeffcient $\eta(\epsilon)$ (also a function of
energy density) is known as shear viscosity. The projector $\Delta^{\mu\nu}$ is defined as $\Delta^{\mu\nu}=u^\mu u^\nu + \eta^{\mu\nu}$.
Use the facts that trace $ T\equiv \eta_{\mu\nu}T^{\mu\nu}=0$, which yields equation of state $P(\epsilon)=\epsilon/3$, and trace of the bulk viscosity term $T^{\mu\nu}=\dots \zeta\Delta^{\mu\nu}\partial_\lambda u^\lambda$ is also $0$.

(a.) Without deriving the dispersion relation for sound determine the speed of sound for fluids with the equation of state $P(\epsilon)=\epsilon/3$.

(b.) We only look at systems for which the trace is zero: $ T\equiv \eta_{\mu\nu}T^{\mu\nu}=0$. The theory is called *conformal* hydrodynamics with equation of state $P(\epsilon)=\epsilon/3$ and $\zeta=0$. Perturb $u^\mu (x)$and $\epsilon(x)$ around constant equilibruim values to first order in small $\delta u^\mu$ and $\delta\epsilon$:

$u^\mu=(1,0,0,0) + \delta u^\mu e^{-i\omega t+ikx},\\  
\epsilon=\epsilon_0 + \delta  \epsilon e^{-i\omega t+ikx}$

This means that $\epsilon_0$, $\delta u^\mu$ and $\delta \epsilon$ are all constant. The only space-time dependence is in the exponentials and it only depends on $t$ and $x$ coordinates (not $y$ or $z$).

Now, consider only transverse fluctuations to the $x$-direction, for example only $\delta u^y$ and set all other fluctuations to zero. By expanding

$\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0$

to first order in fluctuations, derive the dispersion relation for the mode (solve for $\omega(k)$) and show that the solution has the form

$\omega=-i D k^2$.

Find $D$. This is diffusion. Make sure that your solution solves the complete set of equations $\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0$.

(c.) Comment on why diffusion looks so non-relativistic. What breaks the Lorentz invariance of $T^{\mu\nu}$?

Could anyone lend me some advice?

Comment: The assumptions that you are using (traceless energy-momentum) refer to an ultrarelativistic fluid (like a photon gas).  Bulk viscosity, sound and heat diffusion are discussed in [Multifluid Modelling of Relativistic Radiation Hydrodynamics heat diffusion](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.09481).